# Play icon in a button

Tags: youtube, uibutton, xcode4.2, mpmovieplayercontroller

How do I get this play arrow in a button? This arrow should look like if you have an website with an embed YouTube video.

[image]
<sub>(source: [iPhoneIncubator.com](http://iPhoneIncubator.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/youtubeembeddedvideo.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to be playing YouTube content directly from the app there is some information on how to place a UIWebView to display the content from YouTube. Check out Method #2 which demonstrates the creation of this thumbnail.

[YouTube API Information](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html)

For other video sources, you could set the background color of the button to be a still frame of the video using

```
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"videoStill.png"]];
```

Then set the button's image property to a play button with transparency.

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: I added information to the answer from YouTube about how to place some "pretty" buttons into your app. Hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: thanks for your help! I'm going to test it out tommorrow. I will report. Regards
BTW: I m trying to insert the "arrow" in other video sources, not youtube. Regards

Comment: But how to make the play button become for example pink, if you touch it, (example : BBC iPlayer)

Comment: In that case you're going to have to create the two graphics as described. I had the same problem in one of my apps. Also, from my experience, I used a graphic centered in the button to produce the play button.

Comment: but what about the change of colours?

Comment: You can change the highlight color of the button. It will effect the image and tint it according to the `UIColor` you set. Or provide a colorized image and use `setImage:forState:` and set it for `UIControlStateHighlighted`